# eeprom array char чтение и запись codevisionavr

Tags: c, avr

Помогите. Есть необходимость записать данные в энергонезависимую память мк. Видел примеры, но это немного не то что нужно.

Компилятор CodeVisionAVR.

пример переменной которую нужно хранить в eeprom и естественно читать её.

вопрос: есть ли функции которые сразу могут записать в нужную ячейку массива который находиться в eeprom.

```
char day_hour_1[36] =   /*HOUR*/  { 8,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22};
```

Comment: любая EEPROM в той или иной степени ограничена по количеству циклов перезаписи и временным характеристикам чтения/записи, так что обычной практикой является считывание оттуда при запуске и запись при каком-то событии... какие именно есть функции, чтобы читать/писать — смотри в локументации на свой компилятор. В avr-gcc — это абор функций `eeprom_{read,write}_{byte,word,block}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. В CodeVisionAVR это устроенно очень просто.

```
eeprom char testVar = 5;
void main(void){
    testVar = 1; //записываем в EEPROM

}
```